# ERROR File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system

Tags: android, ionic4, pdfmake

I am trying to generate pdf using [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake). I am using table in content, I encounter the error `ERROR File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system`

```
        this.maintainanceLists.forEach(function(sourceRow) {
            var dataRow = [];

            dataRow.push(sourceRow.code_name);
            dataRow.push(sourceRow.created_on);
            dataRow.push(sourceRow.lease_id);
            dataRow.push(sourceRow.property);
            dataRow.push(sourceRow.unit);

            bodyData.push(dataRow)
        });
        var docDefinition = {
            content: [
                {
                    table: {
                        body: bodyData
                    }
                }
            ],
            styles: {
                story: {
                    italic: true,
                    alignment: 'center',
                    width: '100%',
                }
            }
        }
        this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
```

I have imported the pdffonts and pdfmake. 
     `import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfMake';
     import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
     pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.vfs;`

There is no issue when using text in content. The issue is when using table